# A part of a Rule Selector is yellow

Tags: firefox, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDBNH.png)

When i try to use the selector directly in custom CSS

```
a:hover, a:focus, a:active !important {
    color: #fff;
}
```

It doesn't work, while some time ago **it did** (when it wasn't yellow) .

That works:

```
a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

But what the yellow highlight means exactly, and why the first version doesn't work ?

p.s. And which principle of using the Dev Tools should've bring me to the `a` version (found it by trying) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yellow color indicates that a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Pseudo-class) is matching, like `:hover` in your case.

This highlighting is independent from your issue that the selector doesn't match.

The reason why the selector doesn't match is that you placed an `!important` declaration in there. Though `!important` is [only allowed for individual style declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules), *not* in selectors.

[Using `!important` in a selector makes the whole selector invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#invalid).

So the correct selector in your case is `a:hover, a:focus, a:active`.

An explizit hint the Firefox DevTools provide regarding incorrect CSS selectors (as of Firefox 77) is a warning saying "Dangling combinator. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector" within the *Console* when you have the *CSS* filter enabled:

[image: Warning for incorrect CSS selector in Console]

Another indication you get is that CSS rules with invalid selectors don't show up in the *Rules* panel.

An advanced help could be showing CSS errors and warnings within the *Style Editor* as requested in [bug 1171873](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1171873).

Comment: I tried it without `!important` (the same as when it worked), it still doesn't work . though i didn't know about the limitation .

Comment: don't know why i didn't try before, to apply the conditions of "hover, focus, active" . it works as intended when i hover over the target, so i guess, at the 1st time it was some error that made the new color applied all the time .